# Multiply 4-d tensor with 1-d tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I have a rank 4 tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, num_rows, num_cols, num_values]` and a rank 1 Tensor with dimensions `[num_values]`.  I would like to compute the dot product of the values in the fourth column and my rank 1 Tensor, resulting in a rank 4 Tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, num_rows, num_cols, 1]`, which I could then `tf.squeeze` to a Tensor with dimensions `[batch_size, num_rows, num_cols]`.  Does anyone know how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverflowPlease provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) or [`reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum):

```
a = tf.constant(np.random.rand(2, 3, 5, 7))
b = tf.constant(np.random.rand(7))

tf.tensordot(a, b, [-1, -1])  # <tf.Tensor 'Tensordot_1:0' shape=(2, 3, 5) dtype=float64>

tf.reduce_sum(a * b, axis=-1)  # <tf.Tensor 'Tensordot_1:0' shape=(2, 3, 5) dtype=float64>
```

Comment: tf.tensordot(a, b, [-1, -1]) fails with TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len(). But tf.reduce_sum(a * b, axis=-1) works.